# Can I accelerate the zipping speed?

Tags: java, android, zip

Well I was looking to my current zipping code and then I came up with the question, is there any way that I can make it zip faster? I used this code: [Zip Code](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29) I changed the Buffer to a bigger number, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most time in zipping process is spend in deflate algorithm implementation. Lowering compression level will speedup things, but make output larger.

Comment: And how do I lower compression level?

Comment: ZipOutputStream has setLevel() method. 0 is no compression, 9 - highest compression possible. Default value should be 6.

Comment: Will be trying that in a few hours, I hope it wotks. Thanks